# PHP: extract first instance of an ISBN from json

Tags: php, match, isbn

Hi guys so I need to extract the first instance of an ISBN from JSON using PHP. In the case below I need 9781451687866. I am returning book records from a library API and due to the nature of the JSON output a book can have 10 or 13 digit ISBNs associated with it
Anyway I need a way of extracting the first instance of a 13 digit number from a string in an array and setting it equal to a variable. if a 13 digit number doesn't exist then look for a 10 digit number ELSE "no ISBN found" type thing.
FYI: ISBNs can also start with a 0 so I'd need that preserved.
Any ideas how to achieve this? I'm using a for loop to output the records

```html
for($i=0; $i<count($res['entries']); $i++) 
 ...echo "<h4>Title: " . $res['entries'][$i]['bib']['title'] . "</h4>";
```

MUCH appreciated!
Thanks

```
{
"count": 1,
"total": 1,
"start": 0,
"entries": [
  {
    "relevance": 72.32632446289062,
    "bib": {
      "id": "1386855",
      "varFields": [
        {
          "fieldTag": "a",
          "marcTag": "100",
          "ind1": "1",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Buffett, Howard G."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "c",
          "marcTag": "050",
          "ind1": "0",
          "ind2": "0",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "HV696.F6"
            },
            {
              "tag": "b",
              "content": "B84 2013"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "d",
          "marcTag": "650",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": "0",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Food relief"
            },
            {
              "tag": "z",
              "content": "Developing countries."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "d",
          "marcTag": "650",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": "0",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Agricultural development projects"
            },
            {
              "tag": "z",
              "content": "Developing countries."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "d",
          "marcTag": "650",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": "0",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Humanitarianism"
            },
            {
              "tag": "z",
              "content": "Developing countries."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "d",
          "marcTag": "650",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": "0",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Hunger"
            },
            {
              "tag": "z",
              "content": "Developing countries."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "9781451687866 (hardcover : alk. paper)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "1451687869 (hardcover : alk. paper)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "z",
              "content": "9781451687880 (ebook)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "9781451687873 (pbk. : alk. paper)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "1451687877 (pbk. : alk. paper)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "1451687885 (ebook)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "i",
          "marcTag": "020",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "9781451687880 (ebook)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "l",
          "marcTag": "010",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "  2013031452"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "n",
          "marcTag": "504",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Includes bibliographical references (pages 417-423) and index."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "n",
          "marcTag": "505",
          "ind1": "0",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Acknowledgments -- Foreword -- Introduction: one shot at a warlord -- Story 1: How I realized i had only \"40 chances\" -- Story 2: Prague, 1968 : \"The army eats first : we get what is left\" -- Story 3: From bulldozing dirt to planting soil -- Story 4: Devon's gift -- Story 5: Because \"al called\" -- Story 6: The ovarian lottery -- Story 7: Reality has a nutty taste, especially when fried -- Story 8: Where hunger hides -- Bravery, courage, and hope -- Story 9: Loved, but lost -- Story 10: Empty calories -- Story 11: Little cromite -- Story 12: Sex and hunger in Timbuktu -- Story 13: Loss in Armenia -- Story 14: Farming under fire -- Story 15: Seeds of change -- Story 16: Shakira -- Story 17: a franciscan padre in the Sierra Madre -- Story 18: Gorillas v. guerillas -- Hard-learned lessons -- Story 19: Can this village be saved? -- Story 20: A complicated legacy -- Story 21: For yields to go up, we have to look down -- Story 21 1/2: owners make better farmers -- Story 22: What does doing better look like? / by Howard W. Buffett -- Story 23: Disconnects -- Story 25: A six-beer insight -- Story 26: Less than sparkling -- Challenges we need to figure out -- Story 27: Elephants and experts -- Story 28: Can smarter carrots save soil? -- Story 29: Chains that unlock potential / by Howard W. Buffett -- Story 30: A walk to the well -- Story 31: Souped up yields from stripped down tools -- Story 32: Does aid plant seeds of violence? / by Howard W. Buffett -- Reasons to hope -- Story 33: Opening what once was cerrado -- Story 34: Chocolate-covered opportunities -- Story 35: Fired up in Ghana -- Story 36: Buy local! -- Story 37: Hungry for data -- Story 38: The power of a piece of paper -- Story 39: Farmer of the future / by Howard W. Buffett -- Story 40: Help for a \"poor relation\" -- Epilogue: an optimistic pessimist returns to prague."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "n",
          "marcTag": "520",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "If you had the resources to accomplish something great in the world, what would you do? Legendary investor Warren Buffett posed this challenge to his son in 2006, when he announced he was leaving the bulk of his fortune to philanthropy. Howard G. Buffett set out to help the most vulnerable people on earth--nearly a billion individuals who lack basic food security. And Howard has given himself a deadline: 40 years to put more than $3 billion to work on this challenge. Howard learned this lesson through his passion for farming: each farmer can expect to have about 40 growing seasons, giving him just 40 chances to improve on every harvest. This lesson applies to all of us, because we all have about 40 productive years to do the best job we can, whatever our passions may be. This book captures Howard's journey around the world as he seeks out new approaches to ease the suffering of so many.--From publisher description."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "o",
          "marcTag": "001",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "content": "830352188"
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "p",
          "marcTag": "264",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": "1",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "New York :"
            },
            {
              "tag": "b",
              "content": "Simon & Schuster,"
            },
            {
              "tag": "c",
              "content": "2013."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "r",
          "marcTag": "300",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "xiv, 443 pages :"
            },
            {
              "tag": "b",
              "content": "illustrations ;"
            },
            {
              "tag": "c",
              "content": "24 cm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "r",
          "marcTag": "336",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "text"
            },
            {
              "tag": "2",
              "content": "rdacontent"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "r",
          "marcTag": "337",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "unmediated"
            },
            {
              "tag": "2",
              "content": "rdamedia"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "r",
          "marcTag": "338",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "volume"
            },
            {
              "tag": "2",
              "content": "rdacarrier"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "t",
          "marcTag": "245",
          "ind1": "1",
          "ind2": "0",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "40 chances :"
            },
            {
              "tag": "b",
              "content": "finding hope in a hungry world /"
            },
            {
              "tag": "c",
              "content": "by Howard G. Buffett ; with Howard W. Buffett ; foreword by Warren E. Buffett."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "u",
          "marcTag": "246",
          "ind1": "3",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "Forty chances"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "003",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "content": "OCoLC"
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "005",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "content": "20140117012148.0"
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "008",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "content": "130905s2013    nyua     b    001 0 eng  cam i "
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "035",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "(OCoLC)830352188"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "040",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "DLC"
            },
            {
              "tag": "b",
              "content": "eng"
            },
            {
              "tag": "e",
              "content": "rda"
            },
            {
              "tag": "c",
              "content": "DLC"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "YDXCP"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "BDX"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "OCLCO"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "IH7"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "YBM"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "BUR"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "GPI"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "VP@"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "WIQ"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "EEK"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "OCLCF"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "IXA"
            },
            {
              "tag": "d",
              "content": "BET"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "042",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "pcc"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "043",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "d------"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "049",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "BETT"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "y",
          "marcTag": "994",
          "ind1": " ",
          "ind2": " ",
          "subfields": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "content": "C0"
            },
            {
              "tag": "b",
              "content": "BET"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "fieldTag": "_",
          "content": "00000cam  2200000 i 4500"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: A sample of the JSON would help.

Comment: **due to the nature of the JSON output a book can have 10 or 13 digit ISBNs'** What does that mean? please post sample json string

Comment: `ISBNs can also start with a 0` sounds like you are casting the identifier to an integer. Please provide a sample string.

Comment: The ISBN is 13 digits long if assigned on or after 1 January 2007, and 10 digits long if assigned before 2007. It has nothing to do with the "natur of the json output"

Comment: There also are ISSNs. With no sample the question should be closed.

Comment: Just added the JSON. Newbie just trying to learn along the way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely no expert on ISBNs.. So this may not work in every scenario. This could be a starting point for you, potentially.

```
$str1 = 'isbn: 1234567890';
$str2 = 'isbn: 123-1234567890';
$str3 = 'isbn: 1234567890123';

//matches 3 digits, then a hyphen, then 10 digits OR
//matches 10 digits in a row
$regex = '/\d{3}-\d{10}|\d{10}/';

preg_match($regex, $str1, $result1);
preg_match($regex, $str2, $result2);
preg_match($regex, $str3, $result3);

var_dump($result1);
var_dump($result2);
var_dump($result3);
```

Whatever line it is fed, it will extract the 10 digits in a row, or 13 digits if there is a `-` in-between.

Comment: You don't need the `|\d{10}`, just make the initial 3 numbers and hyphen optional. `(?:\d{3}-)?\d{10}`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to solve my issue. Thanks everyone

```
for($q=0; $q<count($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields']); $q++) //loop thru the varFields
{


    if($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$q]['fieldTag'] == "i") //pull out only ISBN fieldTags with a value i
        {


            $subfieldText = $res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$q]['subfields'][0]['content'];
            if (preg_match_all("/\d{13}/", $subfieldText, $matches))
                {
                $isbnDetect = $matches[0];
                echo $isbnDetect[0];
                break;   //if we match a 13 digit ISBN leave conditional
                }
             else if (preg_match_all("/\d{10}/", $subfieldText, $matches))
                 {
                 $isbnDetect = $matches[0]; 
                 echo $isbnDetect[0];
                 break;  //else if we match a 10 digit ISBN leave conditional
                 }

          } 

    else
    {
        $isbnDetect[0] = ""; //if no ISBN clear value
    }



}
```